# Building plugin for ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'd like to build a plugin, that will operate on Ext.Grid and allow some operations on it (adding new rows, updating them on some events etc) What type of component should my plugin extend to achieve best results ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ExtJS Grid provides two ways of adding functionality:

1. Plugins
2. Features

**Plugins:** Plugins provide custom functionality for the component. ExtJS 4 introduced this system so that, developers can inject their custom features to the component. It is specified as an object or array of object using the `plugins` attribute of grid class.

Basically, a plugin is a ExtJS class that usually don't need to extend any ExtJS class. The mandatory part of the plugin class is that, it SHOULD have a `init` method that the plugin system calls to initialize the plugin. This method should take a parameter (which will be a reference to your grid). The init method is supposed to configure all the custom events (if any) or hook up method that listen to events.

Here is a sample skeleton code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.MyPlugin', {
    alias: 'plugin.ux.muplugin',
    init: function(grid) {
        // init events and add listeners...
    },

    customFunction: function(par1, par2) {

       // some code...
    },

});
```

**Features:** Feature is a type of plugin which is only available for the grid panel. The base class for a feature is `Ext.grid.feature.Feature`. You need to extend this class if you are planning to create a feature.

Here is a sample:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.feature.MyFeature', {    
    extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.Feature',

    alias: 'feature.myfeature',

    // other methods..

});
```

This should help you get started.

Comment: "The AbstractPlugin class is the base class from which user-implemented plugins should inherit. This class defines the essential API of plugins as used by Components..." - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractPlugin

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to actually create the plugin file and how to include it in the grid?

Answer (score 3):

If you study given plugins in `src/grid/plugin/*`, they do not specifically extend any base class like what `Ext.form.field.*` do. So, imo, this has to be related to what you need to achieve.

For example, both `RowEditing` and `CellEditing` extends `Editing` as their base class to have the ability to edit grid's store, whereas `HeaderReorder` and `HeaderResizer` just extends `Ext.util.Observable` so to achieve common event handling.

Best bet is to extend `Ext.util.Observable` if none of the functionalities has been implemented in any given classes in Ext, so at least you can still fire up some events.

Plugins is nothing but set of functions added to a Grid object. Correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: Sencha's docs indicate user-implemented plugins should inherit from Ext.AbstractPlugin, per @Asky 's answer.  See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractPlugin

Answer (score 2):

plugins are reusable functionality that are shared across components. all the EXTJS plugins should inherit the class Ext.AbstractPlugin